# What are points for and against the three Farm Bills passed by Indian parliament recently?

Tags: india, agriculture

The Indian Parliament has passed three related Farm Bills recently, and there are mixed opinions regarding these bills.

Why are there mixed reactions regarding these? What are the arguments for and against these bills?

Comment: This is actually not a bad question, but it was basically answered in the linked one...